# How do I open individual files that increment up?

Tags: c, file, printf, cs50, fopen

So I'm doing this homework where I have to go through a memory card and recover some images by putting data into a buffer, creating new JPEG files from that buffer data and then writing that data into those new files to get the images. Right now, I'm stuck on how to open the newly created files using the fopen function in C in order to write that data, and each file is named, "###.jpg", incrementing up from 000.jpg to 050.jpg. I could just open and write the files over and over I guess, but that's obviously instinctively way wrong.

Below is a rough snippet of code to explain my problem. Not really worried about memory allocation or segmentation faults/errors just yet while writing this, I'm just trying to convey my idea so you all understand my problem. I tried putting file_num at the end parameter of fopen after "w", but that just got an error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const BLOCK_SIZE = 512;
int buffer[BLOCK_SIZE];
unsigned int file_num = 0;

int main()
{
    //Open memory card
    FILE *pFile = fopen(card.raw, "r");

    //Open and create JPEG files
    while(fread(buffer, 1, BLOCK_SIZE, pFile) == BLOCK_SIZE)
    {
        if(some condition)
        {
            //Create JPEG file
            sprintf(pFile, "%.03i.jpg", file_num++);

            //Open new JPEG files to write data(this is my problem right here)
            FILE *pImg = fopen(###.jpg, "w");

            ....
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the `sprintf()` to create the filename is quite ok, there is only the '%' missing and you shouldn't use a leading ".". Just use that name in `fopen(pFile, "w")`;

Comment: sorry I've overlooked, that `pFile` is a `FILE *`. You need a char array to store the name, like `char name[20]; sprintf(name,"%03i.jpg", file_num++); FILE *pImg = fopen(name,"w");`

Comment: Whoops! Typo forgetting the %, my bad XD. but my problem is that while I know HOW to open a newly created file, I don't know how to open them consecutively inside the loop. I don't want to create the file and then type in the newly made ###.jpg files individually, since there are supposed to be 50 images once the data is written. That's my problem.

Comment: I don't quite understand where you see a problem. Whenever you decide that you have to create another file, you close the old one, create a new filename (thanks to `file_num++` your `sprintf()` does the trick) and open that file. That's all

Comment: Ummmm FUUUU- ok, imma try something a bit stupid and alter fopen the second time it's used(the one inside the loop). I know it'll look wrong, but trust the process! "FILE *pImg = fopen("%03i.jpg", "w", file_num++);". I think that'll help a bit? Or make it worse, idk.

Comment: you can't use the `sprintf()` format syntax in `fopen()`. You need both functions

Comment: Yes ik, I just wrote that way in the comment hoping it would convey what I was trying to say. I think I’m just too stupid to convey what I’m trying to say tbh

Comment: You are messing up the file name with four file pointer (as Ingo Leonhardt already told you).  Nevertheless, your compiler should tell you that `pFile` is not a `char*` as expected by `sprintf`. If you did not get any hints you need to increase warning level. For GCC try `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`.

Comment: I know, but my problem is on line 21. Ignore everything else, I need help with line 21

Answer (score 2):

You need a character buffer to store the *string* that `sprintf` creates. This string is used as the first argument to `fopen`.

The `printf` format specifier for `unsigned int` is `%u`, not `%i`.

Here is a simple example that creates the files *000.jpg* up to, and including, *050.jpg*.

It also writes the name of each file to the respective file (enclosed in `< >`).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char file_name[64];

    for (unsigned n = 0; n <= 50; n++) {
        sprintf(file_name, "%03u.jpg", n);

        FILE *current_file = fopen(file_name, "w");

        if (current_file) {
            fprintf(current_file, "<%s>\n", file_name);
            fclose(current_file);
        }
    }
}
```

In use:

```
$ ./create_files
$ ls
000.jpg  007.jpg  014.jpg  021.jpg  028.jpg  035.jpg  042.jpg  049.jpg
001.jpg  008.jpg  015.jpg  022.jpg  029.jpg  036.jpg  043.jpg  050.jpg
002.jpg  009.jpg  016.jpg  023.jpg  030.jpg  037.jpg  044.jpg  create_files
003.jpg  010.jpg  017.jpg  024.jpg  031.jpg  038.jpg  045.jpg  create_files.c
004.jpg  011.jpg  018.jpg  025.jpg  032.jpg  039.jpg  046.jpg
005.jpg  012.jpg  019.jpg  026.jpg  033.jpg  040.jpg  047.jpg
006.jpg  013.jpg  020.jpg  027.jpg  034.jpg  041.jpg  048.jpg
$ cat 000.jpg 040.jpg
<000.jpg>
<040.jpg>
$ rm {000..050}.jpg
```